# How to send mail from zimbra command line

Tags: email, command, sendmail, zimbra

I am vikas. i am looking a command that can send mail from zimbra mail-store server to external world. but as i checked in zimbra not getting Any program that have role of sending mails. that is why i am relay email through Zimbra MTA server. now i am going to use below command but still getting variable error.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Subject:test mail!\nFrom:Mailadmin <admin@knowledgelinux.com>"}{printf("%s\015\n", $0)}' $message file-name=/test.txt | sendmail -t "mail@knowledgelinux.com"
```

awk: command not found

Comment: Error message seems self-explanatory: you have no `awk` program installed, or it cannot be found via `PATH`.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with awk. You could replace `awk` with `flubber` and have the same problem. So, I'm removing the awk tag.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions [here](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=23464#p127393) worked for me:

```
vim /etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf
```

Relevant lines to be replaced:

```
Output = mail
MailTo = root_all@your.domain
MailFrom = Logwatch@your.domain
mailer = "/opt/zimbra/common/sbin/sendmail -t"
```

`Zimbra` uses a modified version of `sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

The Zimbra MTA uses a modified postfix daemon. You should be able to just use the command `mail`:

```
cat *messagefilename* |mail -r *fromaddress* -s *Subject* *recipient-list*
```

As long as the Zimbra MTA is running on the machine in question this should work.